# why sort a list generated from converting an array also affects the original array

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

I have an array that I convert it to a list, then I sort that list. The problem I am having is I don't understand why is the original array also get sorted. See the below and the output

[image]

```
Output:
[0, 10, 2, abc]
[0, 10, 2, abc]
```

I am curious to know why the array also get sorted? Thanks in advance

Comment: java.util.Arrays.asList: `Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) `

Comment: @ScaryWombat next time I wont post an image. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` method returns a wrapper `List` object around the supplied array. The returned wrapper `List` has some limitations e.g. you can't call `add()` method because the backing array doesn't support resizing.

If you want to create a new `List` object which is independent from the original array you can use [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
String[] array = { "abc", "2", "10", "0" };
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, array);
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list); // [0, 10, 2, abc]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // [abc, 2, 10, 0]
```